# IOS Reveal View - trigger functions in another UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using the SWRevealViewController class within an IOS 7 app.

I have a front view ( MainHP_TableViewController) and a rear view (messagesTVController), the left view is revealed on right swipe to display messages.

My issue is that I need to trigger a method in the front view when closing the reveal (basically the message count needs to be updated).

I have found an action in the SWRevealViewController to attach an event trigger to and have setup a method in my main view controller to receive it as follows -

**swRevealViewController.m**

```
    MainHP_TableViewController *mhp = [[MainHP_TableViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [mhp readyBtn];
```

**MainHP_TableViewController.m**

```
- (void)readyBtn{

     NSLog(@"passed back");

    _btnNo = 1;

  //  NSLog(@"Value of hello = %@", _btnNo);

    //[self.tableView reloadData];
 }
```

What happens is that the swipe action event works and the passed back message appears in the console - the _btnNo var changes to 1 - but if I un-comment either the NSLog line or the reload data line (screenshot above) the app crashes.. without any error in the console annoyingly..

I can call the same method from a button in the MainHP_TableViewController itself and all works fine - so I'm guessing its some kind of permission issue with the method being called from another controller?  But its giving me a headache - so any tips would be very welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be better to use `NSNotificationCenter`;
in front viewcontroller you can register observer in `viewDidLoad` like:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(notificationRecived:)
                                             name:@"reloadData"
                                           object:nil];
```

and put selector method:

```
- (void)notificationRecived:(NSNotification *)notification {
  if([notification.name isEqualToString:@"reloadData"]) {
     // Do stuff here 
     // [self.tableView reloadData]; 
  }
}
```

in rear viewcontroller you can simply post notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:nil userInfo:nil];
```